# Resources to learn about the AVR/RISC architecture

Tags: avr, atmega, atmel, architecture

I think I have used enough of the AVR series by atmel to say that I understand how to use it. I know somethings about how it actually works, but I would like to know more. Are there any good resources which describe the architecture of Atmega or RISC architecture in general? I know the datasheet has all this (and I really looooovvee the datasheet, its kinda my bible) but I need something little more simple than that. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn AVR assembly, it's the best practical way to learn about the architecture.

http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/

Answer (score 2):

Check out the white papers in the *Other Docs* section of Atmel's website: http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/other_docs.asp?family_id=607#White_Paper .

A long time ago I read the one called *The AVR Microcontroller and C Compiler Co-Design* which explains why they think the AVR instruction set is well-suited for the C language. Some of the other documents there explain the AVR architecture or a series of chips in general.

Answer (score 1):

[AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/).

Comment: I know about the site, but I am looking for a much more concise way to learn.